# I didn't get Nuget Package Manager option on my project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

i didn't get Nuget Package Manager(as well as NPM Console) option on my project? I check Nuget Package Manager tab in option but it was saying error occur. How can i get my NPM back?

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Check this post. http://zsresta.azurewebsites.net/?p=241